# Principal Post Wordpress Category Shortcode Returning “Array”

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I have created some simple shortcodes in the past to get post title and thumbnail image and everything was fine. But now I am struggling to get the primary category of posts and portfolios on Wordpress.

I have included in my functions.php file the next function from [this site](https://www.tannerrecord.com/how-to-get-yoasts-primary-category/):

```
function get_primary_taxonomy_term( $post = 0, $taxonomy = 'category' ) {
    if ( ! $post ) {
        $post = get_the_ID();
    }

    $terms = get_the_terms( $post, $taxonomy );
    $primary_term = array();

    if ( $terms ) {
        $term_display = '';
        $term_slug    = '';
        $term_link    = '';
        if ( class_exists( 'WPSEO_Primary_Term' ) ) {
            $wpseo_primary_term = new WPSEO_Primary_Term( $taxonomy, $post );
            $wpseo_primary_term = $wpseo_primary_term->get_primary_term();
            $term               = get_term( $wpseo_primary_term );
            if ( is_wp_error( $term ) ) {
                $term_display = $terms[0]->name;
                $term_slug    = $terms[0]->slug;
                $term_link    = get_term_link( $terms[0]->term_id );
            } else {
                $term_display = $term->name;
                $term_slug    = $term->slug;
                $term_link    = get_term_link( $term->term_id );
            }
        } else {
            $term_display = $terms[0]->name;
            $term_slug    = $terms[0]->slug;
            $term_link    = get_term_link( $terms[0]->term_id );
        }
        $primary_term['url']   = $term_link;
        $primary_term['slug']  = $term_slug;
        $primary_term['title'] = $term_display;
    }
    return $primary_term;
    }
```

Later I have created a shortcode to get the primary category term from that function:

```
add_shortcode( 'show_category1', 'get_primary_taxonomy_term' );
```

Using the shortcode [show_category1] I just get the word 'Array' and not the category term.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHsmv.png)

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: Your shortcode callback function needs to return _text_. You made it return an array, which when implicitly converted into a text value, will only result in the _word_ “Array”.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `$primary_term` is defined as an array, and the result is obviously an array that contains 'url', 'slug' and 'title' strings. Perhaps try to return something like this:

```
function get_primary_taxonomy_term( $post = 0, $taxonomy = 'category' ) {
    if ( ! $post ) {
        $post = get_the_ID();
    }

    $terms = get_the_terms( $post, $taxonomy );

    if ( $terms ) {
        $term_display = '';
        $term_slug    = '';
        $term_link    = '';
        if ( class_exists( 'WPSEO_Primary_Term' ) ) {
            $wpseo_primary_term = new WPSEO_Primary_Term( $taxonomy, $post );
            $wpseo_primary_term = $wpseo_primary_term->get_primary_term();
            $term               = get_term( $wpseo_primary_term );
            if ( is_wp_error( $term ) ) {
                $term_display = $terms[0]->name;
                $term_slug    = $terms[0]->slug;
                $term_link    = get_term_link( $terms[0]->term_id );
            } else {
                $term_display = $term->name;
                $term_slug    = $term->slug;
                $term_link    = get_term_link( $term->term_id );
            }
        } else {
            $term_display = $terms[0]->name;
            $term_slug    = $terms[0]->slug;
            $term_link    = get_term_link( $terms[0]->term_id );
        }
    }

    $primary_term= '<a href="' . esc_url($term_link) . '">' . esc_attr($term_display) . '</a>';
    return $primary_term;
}
```